# ActionScript game, having trouble implementing decorator class

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, design-patterns

So, I've created a tile based "match 3" game in ActionScript and there are a  few different types of tiles the main tiles are just letter tiles, and then there are special tiles like a bomb for instance and each tile has similar functionality but each one has special functionality.

Right now, I just have a Tile class that handles all of the functionality which is not the way to go. I think a decorator class would be the best route however implementing it, i am running into issues.

So below is how I have it structured, how would I handle storing the tiles in a Vector? and how would I add to stage?

Currently, I store the tiles in a Vector.(I have one Tile class that handles all of the type types which is ugly). If I were to move to a decorator pattern, it seems that I would be storing a Vector of ITile, how would I add "Itiles" which are essentially LetterTiles and BombTiles to stage? I get Type Coercion errors when trying.

Also, the decorator pattern just seems to be basically an interface, which all types would just implement, so for example, if I were to take an existing LetterTile on stage and say it needs to convert to a BombTile, How would I go about changing or updating the current tile into a Bomb tile?

**example:**

```
public interface ITile
{
    function create():void;
    function remove():void;
}
```

and BaseTile.as

```
public class BaseTile extends Sprite
{
    public function create():void
    {
        throw new IllegalOperationError("Must override in concrete class");
    }

    public class remove():void
    {
        throw new IllegalOperationError("Must override in concrete class");
    }
}
```

LetterTile.as

```
public class LetterTile extends BaseTile implements ITile
{
    public override function create():void
    {
        trace("Letter Tile Created");
    }

    public override function remove():void
    {
        trace("Letter Tile Removed");
    }
}
```

BombTile.as

```
public class BombTile extends BaseTile implements ITile
{
    public override function create():void
    {
        trace('Bomb tile created');
    }

    public override function remove():void
    {
        trace('Bomb tile removed');
        doExplosion();
    }

    public function doExplosion():void
    {
         //This would do something different than regular letter tile.
    }
}
```

Hopefully this makes sense, I needed to add as much info as I could without creating a TL;DR

Comment: I don't think this is really the decorator pattern, it's just abstract classes. Whatever the case, separating out your responsibility is a good idea.

Comment: Yeah, I obviously have never used the decorator pattern :) - But from what I've read I should be passing an instance of ITile into each Tile type e.g public function BombTile(Tile:ITile):void { }? Or maybe decorator isn't needed for what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: Decorator is not for that type of functionality let alone it doesn't exists in AS3. It actually doesn't exist in many programming language. You'll find that in Python for sure.

Comment: @Sherdog Yeah, based on what you've shown you don't really need a decorator. You can just make `BaseTile` implement `ITile` (or ditch the `ITile` interface completely, since `BaseTile` already defines the interface), define common behavior in `BaseTile`, and augment behavior by overriding in your sub-class `LetterTile` and `BombTile` classes. You can call `super` to use the original `BaseTile` behavior and add to it.

Comment: Decorator can certainly exist in Actionscript. Check your copy of Actionscript 3 Design Patterns.

Comment: In case you don't own the book https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/actionscript-30-design/9780596528461/ch04s04.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like I said in my comment, this isn't really the [decorator pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), it's just an abstract class `BaseTile`.

To answer your questions whether you use a decorator or base class: you need to use casting. Specifically:

> how would I handle storing the tiles in a Vector?

```
var tiles:Vector.<ITile> = new <ITile>[];

tiles.push(new BombTile());
```

To check what specific tile types are in your vector use the `is` operator, then use the `as` operator to cast to the specific tile type:

```
for each(var tile:ITile in tiles){
    if(tile is BombTile){
        var bombTile:BombTile = tile as BombTile;
        bombTile.explode();
    }else if(tile is LetterTile){
        var letterTile:LetterTile = tile as LetterTile;
        letterTile.letter = "A";
    }
}
```

> and how would I add to stage?

If you have an `ITile`, you must cast to display object:

```
stage.addChild(tile as DisplayObject);
```

If you have a `BaseTile` it already extends `Sprite` so no casting is necessary.

> if I were to take an existing LetterTile on stage and say it needs to
>   convert to a BombTile, How would I go about changing or updating the
>   current tile into a Bomb tile?

This really depends on what exactly you want to do. You can't change an object into another object, but you can certainly replace it in various ways:

```
var tiles:Vector.<ITile> = new <ITile>[];
tiles.push(new LetterTile(), new LetterTile(), ...etc);

function replaceTile(existingTile:ITile, replacementTile:ITile):void {
    var index:int = tiles.indexOf(existingTile);
    stage.removeChild(existingTile as DisplayObject);
    tiles[index] = replacementTile;
    stage.addChild(replacementTile as DisplayObject);
}

function changeTileType(tile:ITile, type:Class):void {
    if( !(tile is type)){
        replaceTile(tile, new type());
    }
}

// Example:
changeTileType(tiles[0], BombTile);
```

Comment: Good answer that should set him on the right path. One note: That type of multiple similar objects based setup is often a good candidate for the use of a Factory type of class able to distribute object, recycle and switch between type (using cloning and parsing) .

Comment: @BotMaster You are correct that a factory is perfect for this. That's why it makes sense to have the Tile wrap a data object. Your factory would read in XML or JSON or whatever, construct the data objects (which I wouldn't do as separate classes in real life), and then you'd just rip through and create your tiles wrapping those data objects.

Comment: @Aaron, this helps me tremendously! The design patterns book made it sound like the decorator was the way to go, but yeah you're right after reading your answer, decorator really isn't needed for this case. Well time to do some refactoring - Thank you again it really puts it in perspective.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use decorator, you could see it as the things that make your tiles different as data objects, then "Decorate" the data with a "shell" that provides the functionality.

So:

```
public class Bomb implements ITileData {
    public function get tileName():String{
        return 'bomb';
    }

    public function get specialEvent():Event{
        return new BombEvent();//you'd write this class elsewhere
    }

    public function get displayClass():DisplayObject {
        return BombSprite;
    }
}
```

```
   public class Tile extends Sprite {
       protected var _tileData:ITileData;
       public function Tile(tileData) {
           _tileData = tileData;
       }
       public function create():void {
           trace(_tileData.tileName, 'created');
           addChild(new _tileData.displayClass();
       }
       public function interact():void {
           dispatchEvent(_tileData.specialEvent);
       }
       //etc.
   }
```

But honestly you don't need to have separate classes that you're decorating to make them all look the same. You could just have one data object type that you load with data to suit your needs.

---

Edit: I like how Aaron inlined your questions and said how his code answers it. I'm going to steal it.

> how would I add "Itiles" which are essentially LetterTiles and BombTiles to stage?

The Tile class as shown extends Sprite, so you can add it to the stage.

> if I were to take an existing LetterTile on stage and say it needs to convert to a BombTile, How would I go about changing or updating the current tile into a Bomb tile?

In the above code, I pass in the ITileData as a constructor parameter, but you could easily change the type of tile by making the tileData settable by a getter/setter pair. You'd want to remove the old graphic and replace it when the setter triggered.

The specialEvent would tell your parent class what had happened when the user interacts with the tile, and the parent class would be responsible for handling the result of having a bomb event or a letter event triggered.

Comment: This has nothing to do with decorating and is actually called "composition"

Comment: Decorating necessarily involves composition :)

Comment: Involvement is one thing but in AS3 that's as far as you go so you are left with only the composition part so let's call a cat a cat and call it composition.

Comment: Although to be fair maybe what I did was more akin to Adapter http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html. To make it Decorator, the wrapped object and the wrapping object would need to have the same Interface. But my implementation does add responsibilities to the wrapped object, which is a key component of Decorator.

Comment: @AmyBlankenship - Thank you for taking the time to answer, This is also a good answer beings it would be more efficient (well at least it seems like it would) but I might go with what Aaron had mentioned however it might not be as efficient I think it tackles my problem -I think if I had 10/20 different tile types, I would probably pursue using the decorator and break down tiles further into the different attributes each one might inherit (if I had a blank tile, it wouldn't need to inherit BaseTile class functionality since it wouldn't use any of the inherited methods.) Thank you again!